# Credit Card Payment in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, e-commerce

I am currently working on an E-Commerce MVC project and was wondering is there a way to go about verifying a credit card via its CVV number without registering and paying a Credit Card Verification company or are there any Credit Card Verification companies that have a trial-based or free service available

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because it's not about programming.

Comment: No, & there better not be for obvious privacy concerns.

Comment: No, of course not, but there are plenty of third-party services with easy APIs that only charge a fee per actual transaction (rather than some sort of monthly service charge). I've personally used Stripe in the past and found it very easy and functional. They also have a developer mode where you can run full transactions with real cards without actually charging the cards, which gives you a nice way to test your application safely.

Answer (score 1):

the only real way to test a credit card is to put a charge on it - but that still doesn't tell you if the final transaction will go through. some companies do a small charge to test the card and then reverse the charge. the credit card can be valid but

- the amount of the final transaction exceeds the credit card limit
- the issuer of the credit card can reject or hold the transaction if it appears
  fraudulent

major credit card processors have developer areas and 'sandboxes' so you can test verifying cards, doing transactions etc. authorize.net paypal and stripe are some of the most popular.